# Installing NLTK is not performed

Tags: python, nltk, multiple-versions

I checked my usr/local/bin folder, and I have two versions of Python: v. 2.7.5 (used by Terminal) and Python 3.3 that I use with Eclipse.
The image of the bin folder is attached (I might be mistaken about what versions are installed, there might be more). [image: bin folder]
It doesn't seem to be the case that I have Python 2.x.y version collision (with another 2.x.z version).

When I try to install NLTK for v. 2.7 according to the instructions - using their installer/setup script, I get the message that there is no such module.

How can I fix this? I'd like to use NLTK (It used to work just fine in the past).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you open a shell and type "sudo pip install nltk"?

Comment: A long set of lines, one of the last ones says: "Cannot locate working compiler"

Comment: You need to install the `Apple Command Line Tools` for your platform and try the pip install again.

Comment: There is no Command Link Tools package for my platform (OS X 10.6.8).

Comment: Now trying to install the CLT @VooDooNOFX